Anomalous dimension must be positive in Ginzburg-Landau $\phi^4$-like theories?
I am trying to understand/find the argument behind a claim made in this paper (page 3, column 1): that the anomalous dimension/exponent $\eta$ of a continuous phase transition in Ginzburg-Landu $\phi^4$-like theories must be positive. The authors cite Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena by Zinn-Justin, but I find only the claim, not the reasoning behind it.
In Sec 25.5 of the 4th edition, Zinn-Justin calculates the scaling behavior of the vertex functions of a classical $\phi^4$ theory in momentum space, finding that the 2-point function behaves as
$$W^{(2)}(p) \sim 1/p^{2-\eta},$$
for small momentum $p\equiv|\mathbf{p}|$ (Eq. 25.68). Below this Zinn-Justin writes, "The spectral representation of the two-point function implies $\eta > 0$." However, looking at Sec 6.9, I do not see how the results stated lead to this conclusion.
My original expectation was that the inverse Fourier transform of a function with small momentum behavior power law behavior $p^{-(2-\eta)}$ would be ill-defined if $\eta > 0$, but looking at a table of Fourier transforms, that appears not to be the case. The table on Wikipedia lists the Fourier transform of $|\mathbf{x}|^{-\alpha}$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a $d$-dimensional vector, as $|\mathbf{p}|^{-(d-\alpha)}$, with the restriction that $0 < \alpha < d$. If we impose $d-\alpha = 2 - \eta$ this translates to $\alpha = d - 2 + \eta$ (giving the expected decay of a two-point correlation function in real space, $|\mathbf{x}|^{-(d-2+\eta)}$) with the restriction $2-d < \eta < 2$. This argument appears to restrict $\eta > 0$ only in $d = 2$, so presumably there is something I am missing or misinterpreting.
Can anyone explain or provide a more detailed reference (preferably available online) for the claim that $\eta$ must be $> 0$, not just that it happens to be positive?
(For completeness, Sec 6.9 of Zinn-Justin deals with field renormalization in a quantum field theory in Euclidean space, and the result they give there is
$$W^{(2)}(p) = \frac{Z}{p^2 + m^2} + \dots,$$
where I believe $p$ is the $3$-momentum, not the Wick-rotated $4$-momentum, if that makes a difference. There is a restriction on the field-renormalization factor as $0 < Z < 1$. (The above equation follows from Eqs. 6.90 and 6.91).
As far as I can tell, in this chapter $Z$ is not a function of momentum (being the residue of the pole of the two-point function at $p^2 = -m^2$), so it doesn't seem to me that this is relevant to the sign of the anomalous dimension. As far as I can gather this is just the section in which Zinn-Justin introduces the Fourier transform of the two-point function.)

The following method of proving $\eta \geq 0$ wasn't so standard when this 2003 paper came out but it can get to the result very quickly. The critical point is described by a conformal field theory where a state can be created by acting on the vacuum with a scalar $\phi$ at the origin. This produces a primary state with scaling dimension $\Delta_\phi$:
\begin{align}
\left | \phi \right > &\equiv \phi(0) \left | 0 \right >, \quad K_\mu \left | \phi \right > = 0, \quad D \left | \phi \right > = \Delta_\phi \left | \phi \right >.
\end{align}
We can then use the fact that $P^\dagger_\mu = K_\mu$ in radial quantization and demand that states obtained from $\left | \phi \right >$ with the action of $P_\mu$ have non-negative norm. In particular
\begin{align}
\left < \phi | K^2 P^2 | \phi \right > \geq 0.
\end{align}
Simplifying this inequality (and assuming $\Delta_\phi \neq 0$) will give the unitarity bound $\Delta_\phi \geq \frac{d - 2}{2}$ which is equivalent to $\eta \geq 0$ since the order parameter satisfies
\begin{align}
\left < \phi(0) \phi(r) \right > = r^{-2\Delta_\phi} = r^{2 - d - \eta}.
\end{align}
One source I like which discusses the relation between this derivation and the ones in Minkowskian signature is the set of TASI 2019 lectures by David Simmons-Duffin.

The key here is positivity. If you take a signed linear combination of propagators with different masses, e.g.,
$$
\frac{1}{p^2+m_1^2}-\frac{1}{p^2+m_2^2}=\frac{m_2^2-m_1^1}{(p^2+m_1^2)(p^2+m_2^2)}
$$
you can make this decay as (polynomially) fast as you want as $p\rightarrow\infty$.
This is the idea behind Pauli-Villars regularization.
However, if you take positive linear combinations, including continuous sums (i.e. integrals) instead of ordinary discrete sums where all the coefficients or weights are non negative, e.g.,
$$
2\frac{1}{p^2+m_1^2}+\sqrt{\pi}\frac{1}{p^2+m_2^2}+\int_1^2 dm \frac{e^m}{p^2+m^2}
$$
the fastest decay at infinity you can get is still $\frac{1}{p^2}$. You can even decay slower if you do it on purpose, see my MO answer
https://mathoverflow.net/a/270104/7410
The spectral representation, or Källén-Lehmann representation of $W^{(2)}(p)\sim\frac{1}{p^{2-\eta}}$ is such a positive linear combination of propagators with different masses, and therefore since no decay faster than $\frac{1}{p^2}$ is allowed, we must have $\eta\ge 0$.
The stronger conclusion $\eta\neq 0$ needs a separate argument, e.g., Pohlmeyer's Theorem.
